# is using sharepoint as a public website no longer recommended

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I read this statement from this post: [Client Side Rendering & SEO optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311879/client-side-rendering-seo-optimization), is this true. and is there any reference about that.

is this apply on on-premises, and not recommend to use it for public sites?

Comment: What you mean by on prem public site, you can use publishing portal and customized it according to your need as other customer doing...then licensing will be another issue....

Comment: the question: is Microsoft recommend use SharePoint to build public sites? and reason of question is: they deprecated there SharePoint Online public sites, then how they can recommend to use it for on-premises solutions.

Comment: Msft still support it, as they have licensing for internet users...for me online is totally different from on prem....we have sites on Internet which are fully supported n resigned by them...so I would say don't confuse public site with on prem.

Answer (score 0):

This statement comes not from Microsoft. The feature is (and would be for several years) still supported in the current version (Mainstream Support (4/10/2018), Extended Support (4/11/2023), see [source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sofocle/archive/2013/10/01/sharepoint-product-lifecycle.aspx)), and hopefully will be included in the upcoming version as well (that means approximately another 5 years support).

If you plan for 15-20 years, you might consider such strategic possibilities, but as long as public web sites of really large companies rely on this platform, I don't think you should have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not matter of recommendation rather it is matter of requirement. As we all know, MSFT no more offering the Public Web sites for new signup.

The existing SharePoint Online Public Website feature was designed for customers who needed only a basic online presence. You cant do much with MSFT offered Public website and less popular / usage. So, MSFT prioritize the things on which they want to spend more time.

With 3rd party offering, we will get more robust solution  and tools. Please read the below blog for limitation on Public site.

[Limitations of a Public Facing Website in Office 365](http://msftplayground.com/2014/03/limitations-of-a-public-facing-website-in-office-365/)

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/158841.aspx

[Information about changes to the SharePoint Online Public Website feature](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3027254)

Comment: what about on-premises pubic sites?

Comment: I'm not sure I would rush to change a current deployment I was otherwise happy with @jobin but sharepoint for a new website deployment strikes me as a poor choice now.